# Adding row into DataTable

Tags: c#

How  to add rows into datatable without foreach loop by reading records from csv ?

```
var records = File.ReadLines(FD.FileName, Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1);
//not working because datatable is not thread safe
Parallel.ForEach(records, record => dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split(',')));
//using for each is taking aroung 13 sec for 45000 records, need a better solution than this.
foreach (var record in records)
 {
 dataTable.Rows.Add(record.Split(','));
 }
```

Comment: If you mean "How to add rows in parallel", then answer is "You can't", because `DataRowCollection` isn't thread-safe, thus, doesn't support concurrent write access. What do you need this for?

Comment: Looks like you might have an XY problem.

Comment: my main requirement is to add rows into datatable as i'm using foreach loop it is taking 12 sec time for 50000 rec but i want to reduce this.

Comment: @PujithReddy: I doubt that ultimately you just want to create `DataTable` object. What are you going to do with it? `DataTable`s are not well-suited for bulk/batch operations.

Comment: i want to display this data in win form datagridview , any better approach ?

Comment: @PujithReddy: this is indeed XY-problem. I suggest you to rename your question. Posted possible solution below.

Comment: Dupe, the thing to search is "slow add datable C#". the issue is not the foreach. no need to paralele. the issue came from the datatable. From emmrory there is event trigerring, you can use a load data mode on datable, or use a collection (list) and project it to datable in the end.

Comment: Are you sure adding to the datatable is the slow part and not reading from the file? Since you are using `ReadLines` you are streaming the results which mean that they are not read until you iterate the enumerable. So to measure this you can add a `.ToList()` after the `.Skip(1);`.

Comment: Add Range() create all row and add them at once, may also be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a library like LINQ to CSV?

[LINQ to CSV library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library)

I have used it recently and its pretty good.

Basically you set the structure in your class like below

```
using LINQtoCSV;
using System;
class Product
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "ProductName", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 2, OutputFormat = "dd MMM HH:mm:ss")]
    public DateTime LaunchDate { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 3, CanBeNull = false, OutputFormat = "C")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 4)]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [CsvColumn(FieldIndex = 5)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

There after use the below code to read the file

```
CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    SeparatorChar = ',', 
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
};
CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
IEnumerable<Product> products =
    cc.Read<Product>("products.csv", inputFileDescription);
// Data is now available via variable products.
var productsByName =
    from p in products
    orderby p.Name
    select new { p.Name, p.LaunchDate, p.Price, p.Description };
// or ...
foreach (Product item in products) { .... }
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: i'm able to read csv without any difficulty but my point is to render csv data to datagridview since csv is having about 45000 records with foreach it is taking aroung 12 sec but i need to optimize this

Comment: Have a look at this nuget package, I haven't used it before so I dont know how it performs to output into datatable https://github.com/phatcher/CsvReader

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure, that you don't need to display 50000 of rows at once.
Just because this is not human-readable.

Consider pagination: load first N rows, then, when user clicks "Next page" button, load next N rows, and so on.

Having this class for data row:

```
public class MyDataRow
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

pagination demo will be like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int PageSize = 10;
    private readonly BindingList<MyDataRow> dataRows;
    private readonly IEnumerator<string> csvLinesEnumerator;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // start enumeration
        csvLinesEnumerator = ReadLines().Skip(1).GetEnumerator();
        // assign data source to DGV
        dataRows = new BindingList<MyDataRow>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataRows;
        // fetch first page
        FetchNextPage();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => FetchNextPage();

    private void FetchNextPage()
    {
        // disable notifications
        dataRows.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        try
        {
            dataRows.Clear();

            while (dataRows.Count < PageSize)
            {
                if (csvLinesEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    // parse next line and make row object from line's data
                    var lineItems = csvLinesEnumerator.Current.Split(',');
                    var row = new MyDataRow
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(lineItems[0]),
                        Name = lineItems[1]
                    };

                    // add next row to the page
                    dataRows.Add(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // enable notifications and reload data source into DGV
            dataRows.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
            dataRows.ResetBindings();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is just File.ReadLines replacement for testing purposes
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<string> ReadLines()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 50001; i++)
        {
            yield return $"{i},{Guid.NewGuid()}";
        }
    }
}
```

UI:

[image]

Another option is to use [`DataGridView.VirtualMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode?view=net-5.0), but it mostly optimized for cases, when you know the total number of rows (e.g., you can count them via SQL query), which isn't true for CSV files.